# notify-send not working from script - but works from CLI

Tags: linux, scripting, raspberry-pi

Good Day,
  I am new to Linux (Raspberry) and am trying to get notify-send to work from a script (see below).

Notify send works from the terminal CLI and displays on my GUI.  But it does not work from the script.
  I am using Raspberry Buster - with all updates.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This should point to the pivoyager executable
PIVOYAGER=/usr/local/bin/pivoyager

while true;
do
   # Phase 1: Check every 5 seconds if we are USB powered.
   #          If we are not on USB power, go to phase 2.
   while $PIVOYAGER status flags | grep "pg";
   do
      sleep 5
   done


   # Phase 2: Do something before shutdown. (optional)
   #          e.g. send an email, warn users, etc.
   #notify-send "We are on Battery Power.  Save all your work."
   sleep 30



   # Just check if power was miraculously restored.
   if ! $PIVOYAGER status flags | grep "pg"; then
      break
   else
      notify-send "Power was restored. Shutdown aborted!"
   fi
done

# Phase 3: Initiate the shutdown.
#          - Enable automatic power on once USB power is restored.
#          - Program full power cut in 25 seconds.
$PIVOYAGER enable power-wakeup
$PIVOYAGER watchdog 25
sudo shutdown now
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: Kamil,  I have a service that I run from systemd which calls the pivoyager script. Dave

Comment: Kamil, I am not sure the "How to use notify-send to notify users as root?" solves my problem.  I am not root when running the script.   Or am I?  Dave

Comment: From the answer there: "The command `notify-send` needs the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` set and must be called with the owner of this session bus as user." If the script runs from a systemd service then these conditions are *not* automatically met. I don't know as what user the service runs; you should know.

Comment: @Kamil,  What user is running the service?  Yes, in hindsight I do know this.  It is user "pi".  "pi" is the only user on the system.  So, how do I set the environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, such that each time "pi" or better yet - any user should log in the variable is set?

Comment: "`pi` is the only user on the system" – I bet there is `root`. Well, if the variable, when it works, is always the same (`unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus`?), add it to `/etc/profile` or hardcode in the script. You will still need to run `notify-send` as the right user, I think (`sudo -u pi notify-send …`?).

Comment: @Kamil, yes, there is "root". My bad.

Comment: @Kamil, this is the path statement from "/etc/profile".                                                                                                                       if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi

Comment: @kamil, so I would change the second path statement to read: 
 
 PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/run/user/1000/bus"                                       correct? and the reboot to test.

Comment: @kamil, or I would add the "PATH=/run/user/1000/bus" right after "PIVOYAGER=..." in my script?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `PATH`. Research how to set an environment variable in Linux. `PATH` is one variable and you need a *separate* `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable.

Comment: @Kamil, understand - makes sense as I re-read.  Many, many thanks - I will research how to set an environment variable in Linux.  Again, many thanks !